# minimum number of points needed to define a unique 2 degree curve

Tags: conic-sections

as the title says to find minimum number of points needed to define a unique 2 degree.
i did it by thinking that in general equation of 2 degree $Ax^2 + By^2 + 2Gx + 2Fy + 2Hxy + C $ there are 6 variables and there so minimum 6 points are needed to define a 2 degree curve.
is my approach correct ? if not please tell how to solve this problem.
thanks

Comment: If it is a circle you need only 3 points, so the minimum must be equal or smaller  than 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general case, [you need 5 points to determine a conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic) . The minimum is 3 points, circle case. Not much to prove here considering there are three types of conics 
1. Parabola
2. Circle and ellipse
3. Hyperbola

Comment: is there any prove to it?

Comment: There are 6 variables in the formula but they are not all independent .If you double each of them the formula still totals zero. If H=0 the formula can be re-arranged (complete the squares) to yield a standard form for a conic section or a "degenerate conic section" (2 lines,1 line,1 point,or the empty set).If H is not 0, you change  x,y to the co-ordinates u,v with respect to a different pair of  orthogonal axes ,to get a quadratic form in u,v for which the co-efficient of uv is zero.